# Simple web tool for viewing log

Tags: web-server, monitoring, logging, saltstack

I'm developing a server deployment script that installs a bunch of stuff and generates a log in the process. I'd like users of the script to be able to view what's happening, on a web page, in real time (eg, without browser refresh). What's a simple way to make this happen?

I tried [log.io](http://logio.org) but missed the part about "no persistence layer". Tools like nagios are far too complex for this.

Basically I'm looking for something that goes:

1. sudo apt-get install -y logviewer
2. nohup logviewer --port 1234 < /var/log/mylog.log &

The target server is Ubuntu on OpenStack. The log is mostly generated by Salt Stack.

Comment: I've always wanted this, and have searched from time to time.
This looks promising: http://tailon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: It does look promising. Why not make that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @SteveBennett may you so nice to accept an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always wanted this, and have searched from time to time.

This looks promising: http://tailon.readthedocs.org/en/latest

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP already solved his problem, however for posterity I can recommend following tool: [Logdy.dev](https://logdy.dev). You can use an option to stream the logs to the UI and at the same time save it to a file, which then can be restored and pumped to the UI again.